# Definition of Derivative of Matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let's assume **A** is $n\times 1$ constants, **$X$** is $n\times 1$ vector. Does derivative of **transpose**(**A**)* **X** on **X** should be **transpose**(**A**) instead of **A**?

I saw both **transpose**(**A**) and **A** from different resources and would like to confirm the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let me write by $A^t$ the transpose of $A$.

I'm assuming that you're asking about the derivative of the function: $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} : X \mapsto A^t X$ ?

*Short answer:* the derivative is the same map: $(\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} : X \mapsto A^t X)$, in other words, $A^t$

*Slightly longer answer:* for any *linear* map $B : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, its derivative is itself (*ie*, it's the same map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$). The reason for that is because the derivative $Df_x$ of a map $f$ at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as the (unique) linear map  which gives a first-order Taylor approximation, *ie*, such that:

$f(x + \varepsilon) = f(x) + Df_x(\varepsilon) + O(\varepsilon^2)$ for any small $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

When $f = B$ is linear, then we can choose $Df$ to be $B$ itself, and unicity guarantees that it's the only choice, so that the derivative of any linear map is itself.

Comment: This is correct, but I don’t think gets at the heart of the matter. I think the issue is really that people use gradient and derivative synonymously. Hence the OP’s confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mind to have a look at (69) of matrixcookbook (https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)? I was wondering is it an error there or I misunderstood？

Comment: The notation used in that cookbook has the convention that the derivative is the gradient rather than the transpose of the gradient.  This is a common cause of confusion- you need to check the notation used in each source that you refer to.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I was confused on that.